# How to change the spacing before and after a quote environment?

Tags: spacing, quoting

I'm using the `book` class and I would like to change the default spacing before and after a `quote` environment.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Your objective is a bit vague: Would you like to increase or decrease the vertical whitespace above and below a `quote` environment? Should the adjustment factor be multiplicative or additive? What line-spacing is in effect: Single-spacing, double-spacing, or something else? Please elaborate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tapping into the beginning/ending part of an environment in order to insert content (spacing, for example), is made easy using [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox):

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum,etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{quote}{\vspace{2\baselineskip}}% Stuff before {quote}
\AtEndEnvironment{quote}{\vspace{1.5\baselineskip}}% Stuff after {quote}
\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{quote}
  \lipsum[2]
\end{quote}

\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Non-ideal about this approach is that it only add (subtracts) from the given space rather than sets the space itself.

Comment: @Daniel: Consider creating your own quotation environment then... using something like [this](https://pastebin.com/raw/vdAvCy29).