# Determine equal spacing before and after minted environment

Tags: spacing, minted

I have some code in a *minted*-environment that I want to separate from the rest of the text by **equal** spacing before and after the environment. I successfully used the method described [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/248513/how-to-change-the-spacing-before-and-after-a-quote-environment) for an approximately equal spacing, but two questions remain:

a) How can the distance **below** the environment be **reduced**?

b) How can I determine the exact amount for the two spacings to be equal, especially with the usage of `\onehalfspacing`?

MWE of my code below.

```
\documentclass[paper=a4,pagesize,12pt,headinclude,headsepline,footlines=1,parskip=half-,toc=bibliography,abstracton]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[usenames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[newfloat]{minted}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\renewcommand{\theFancyVerbLine}{\ttfamily\color{Gray}{\scriptsize\arabic{FancyVerbLine}}}
\setminted{breakindent=16.9pt,breaklines,breaksymbol=,fontsize=\scriptsize,frame=single,linenos,numbersep=3pt,rulecolor=\color{Gray}}

\onehalfspacing % line spacing

\AtBeginEnvironment{minted}{\vspace{8pt}}% Stuff before {minted}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{minted}{csharp}
Some test code...
\end{minted}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```